# Using Vanilla JS to select data from Table

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am hosting my site using XAMPP and I have a database connection I can reference.

I have 3 drop down menus titled: Translations, books, chapters.  The data for each is stored in my db.

I want to use Vanilla JS to query the dropdown menu content for books based on the users input for translations.

Example: If the user selects "English", the books dropdown display all English books as soon as English has been selected.

I want these dropdowns to update in real time using fetch if possible.  I plan on using this multiple times, I would like to have the Query on my main page and the server / database connection on another.

How would I create a JS function to run a query based on the value of one dropdown menu and pull data from a connection referenced on another file?

Example:

**book.html**

```js
async function fetchBooks() {
  const selectedTranslation = document.getElementById('translations').value;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `/getBooks?translation=${selectedTranslation}`,
    );
    const books = await response.json();

    const booksDropdown = document.getElementById('books');
    booksDropdown.innerHTML = '';

    books.forEach((book) => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = book;
      option.textContent = book;
      booksDropdown.appendChild(option);
      console.log(option);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching books:', error);
  }
}
```

**database.js**

```js
// server.js

const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'dataBase',
});

app.get('/getBooks', (req, res) => {
  const selectedTranslation = req.query.translation;
  const query = `SELECT DISTINCT book FROM english`;

  connection.query(query, [selectedTranslation], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching books:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch books' });
    } else {
      const books = results.map((result) => result.book);
      res.json(books);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: MySQL runs on the server, not the client. You need to use AJAX to call an API on the server to perform the query.

Comment: Can I use fetch instead of AJAX?  If so, how would I use that?   I am trying to be as vanilla as possible

Comment: @adamcapjones he doesn't mean jQuery's `$.ajax()`, he means the more generic [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX) term. And yes, `fetch()` is the modern implementation

Comment: It's not clear where XAMPP comes into anything here. Are you actually running an Express server? Is it also serving your front-end HTML code? What does the code above do? How does it not work?

Comment: This is code I was playing with but it doesn't work.  I posted it to show my train of thought.  
I would prefer to use AJAX and fetch to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using XAMPP. XAMPP is based on PHP as the server side, which means you need to setup a database connection using PHP (If you want to us NodeJS for the server side then you don't really need XAMPP).

After that you need to write a method that queries your database and return data based on the input in a format that is easy to work with, such as JSON.

Then, that function should be called from a new API which will be called from the client side using javascript to receive the data asynchronously.

Once the data is received you should updated the UI to show it to the user.

Comment: Okay, can you walk me through what that would look like?  

I am really struggling with the syntax and how to reference everything.

Comment: It's a lot for a single answer, but take a look at this guide for example - it should do the trick: https://shashanksrivastava.medium.com/create-a-rest-api-using-php-mysql-60ba1ad918d2